# How can I achieve hover effect with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, hover

I am trying to recreate the hover effect the products have at this [website](https://chaldal.com/fresh-fruit).

I know about the `$(".element").hover();` command but can't seem to make it work.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 0):

To trigger the hover event you can write your code like this

```
$('.element').on({
    "hoverenter" : function() {
        // hover enter effet
    },
   "hoverleave" : function() {
       // hover out effet
    }      
});
```

Comment: As for the semi transparent element that pops up, should I use a div or a span?

Comment: "hoverenter" - do you want to rethink those events?